# When and where does Wubi mount it's virtual disks?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, wubi

My use of the `wubi-new-virtual-disk` command made Wubi start mounting this new virtual home disk over my `/home` folder. After the use of the script failed, I am left with Wubi constantly remounting an empty virtual disk over my `/home` folder. I followed the instructions on the Ubuntu website to revert the change, but the mounting continues.

Where did Wubi put the mount operation, and how can I remove it?

EDIT: I solved the above, but my system was still malfunctioning. It hung during shutdown, and randomly broke. I reinstalled Linux.